# What is the significance of the CHANGING keyword when a method is called in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I understand what `IMPORTING` and `EXPORTING` keywords do, but what is the significance of the `CHANGING` keyword?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IMPORTING` passes an actual parameter as a formal parameter, thus transferring a value from the caller to the method. `EXPORTING` does the exact opposite, taking a value from the method and transferring it back to the caller. `CHANGING` combines these, transferring the value both from the caller to the method an back again, with any changes that happened in between.

Note that while `IMPORTING` and `EXPORTING` are reversed between declaration and call, `CHANGING` is not.

Comment: So effectively, `CHANGING` is the ABAP equivalent of call by reference?

Comment: @amalantony: No. In many other programming languages, the concepts of "in/out/inout" parameters and "call by value/reference" are linked - not in ABAP. You can decide whether you want to pass a value or a reference independently of specifying the direction the contents are going.

Answer (score 4):

Also, when declaring Subroutines with `FORM` and `ENDFORM`, the `CHANGING` keyword can be used either like `CHANGING myvar` or `CHANGING VALUE(myvar)`.

`CHANGING myvar` makes it so that the value of `myvar` is changed as soon as it is changed in the subroutine.

In contrast, if `CHANGING VALUE(myvar)` is used, if the form does not return properly (if it throws an exception by example), the value of `myvar` will remain unchanged, in the calling code, even if it was changed in the subroutine that crashed.